# Signature spell damage comparison with attack speed

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Shock Pulse with Piercing Orb fires at what appears to be a very low speed compared to Electrocute with Lightning Blast. Shock Pulse runed is listed to have 105%wd piercing, and Electrocute has 80%wd piercing.

Does the attack speed (animation?) matter for these two spells? It seems to me that for every Shock Pulse I cast, I'll cast at least 2.X Electrocutes in the same amount of time.

To clarify a little (I'm asking about overall effective DPS on a single target that isn't moving), does every single bolt from Electrocute do 80% of weapon damage (I assume that each Shock Pulse orb does 105%), and if it does, would Electrocute be better since you cast more in the same amount of time (so you would have 160%+)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While skills refer to percentages of weapon DPS, they each have [internal attack and pulse rates](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/blue-on-skill-dot-and-tool-tip-simplifications) that are not mentioned in the tooltips. Generally, they refer to the overall damage you'll see *per second*, and the damage values you'll see per individual hit will reflect that. If you're using passives like Prodigy or effects such as gaining Arcane Power on crits, you might find more use out of faster attacks like Electrocute despite their lower damage in general.

While not being a specific answer to the question, [this post on wizard weapon selection and attack speeds](http://d3db.com/blue/thread/3424908246/us) may offer additional insight into why things work this way.

(Note that while the first link refers to DoTs and channeled skills, it appears to be generally applicable to all skills in the game, and my personal testing seems to reinforce that point. If anyone has non-anecdotal evidence to oppose that, please share!)

Comment: Electrocute would have have 35% weapon damage per hit with a faster attack speed, and it levels out to be a base 80% without any modifiers, correct? So no matter what the rate of fire is, the tooltip that lists the weapon damage will always be correct?

Comment: Currently it appears to be the case, yes, with small fluctuations for min/max damage. Without more precise data it's hard to be certain, but it appears to adhere to character sheet Damage being the damage per second you'd put out with a 100% weapon DPS attack.

Answer (score -1):

the attack speed count for the left click skill so y electrocutes is faster x)
But the damages are low :(